# Glassfish - Unable to open Admin Console - throws NPE

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have a Glassfish 3.1 production server that is suddenly acting up.  Last week it was fine.  This morning the it is throwing an NPE when attempting to load the admin console (localhost:4848).  It is also throwing this same error when trying to run 3 of the 4 applications on the server.  One of the apps works fine.  All of the apps are JSF with LDAP security.

I have a test server on a different box that uses **nearly** the same configuration files and works fine.

The server is Win2003R2SP2.  Java is jdk1.6.0_26.
I have restarted the service and even rebooted the host server.
I have also tried the -Dcom.sun.enterprise.tools.admingui.NO_NETWORK=true setting.

These are the log entries that occur when I attempt to connect to the Admin Console or run one of these applications:

```
     [#|2011-09-28T09:15:53.059-0400|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter|_ThreadID=21;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|PWC3989: An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:922)
at org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.remove(ManagerBase.java:915)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:769)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:757)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(StandardSession.java:587)
at org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.createSession(ManagerBase.java:762)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.createSession(StandardManager.java:311)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2899)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2561)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:920)
at org.glassfish.admingui.common.security.AdminConsoleAuthModule.validateRequest(AdminConsoleAuthModule.java:169)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.jmac.config.GFServerConfigProvider$GFServerAuthContext.validateRequest(GFServerConfigProvider.java:1171)
at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.validate(RealmAdapter.java:1311)
at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.invokeAuthenticateDelegate(RealmAdapter.java:1189)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:551)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:623)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:600)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:96)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:228)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
|#]

[#|2011-09-28T09:15:53.105-0400|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|PWC3989: An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:922)
at org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.remove(ManagerBase.java:915)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:769)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:757)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(StandardSession.java:587)
at org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.createSession(ManagerBase.java:762)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.createSession(StandardManager.java:311)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2899)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2561)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:920)
at org.glassfish.admingui.common.security.AdminConsoleAuthModule.validateRequest(AdminConsoleAuthModule.java:169)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.jmac.config.GFServerConfigProvider$GFServerAuthContext.validateRequest(GFServerConfigProvider.java:1171)
at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.validate(RealmAdapter.java:1311)
at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.invokeAuthenticateDelegate(RealmAdapter.java:1189)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:551)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:623)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:600)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:96)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:228)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
|#]
```

Any suggestions on what to look into would be greatly appreciated.  I can post more configurations as needed.

Thanks

Comment: Which is the language of the admin console? I remember that I had exceptions when accessing the Realm configurations in a non-english language. This is a known bug.

Comment: US-English - I don't know any other non-programming languages. :)

Comment: I have made progress in this.  It appears to be an issue with timeouts and restoring sessions.  The production server had this line in the server config area:  session-properties timeout-in-seconds="0".  This appears to have caused the above npe.  Removing it and restarting the server has allowed me back and and the applications are working.  I just need to figure out how to get timeout turned off without this error.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same exception after it was necessary to kill all the Glassfish processes via a command line `kill -9` command. A normal `asadmin restart-domain` was not possible to execute.

So after this forced kill the admin web-frontend was not available anymore.

I've solved this problem by executing

```
asadmin set server.web-container.session-config.session-properties.timeout-in-seconds=3600
```

After that I restarted Glassfish via the normal

```
asadmin restart-domain
```

and then the Glassfish Admin console appears like usual.