# how can I avoid connection time out in glassfish jsf?

Tags: linux, http, jsf, glassfish

I have a site deployed in JSF, running on glassfish server. I am not sure what is happening but after few minutes idle connection doesn't work longer and client has to refresh the page to make it works again. I know about paremeters in Pool Settings and HTTP Service but this is not clear to me: particularly I don't want to set this time after which client has to refresh page to **some** minutes, every website that I know **never** do such thing! So I want my website to work still if he opened it, then left and now he returns after 2 weeks, because he has this still open in browser. Is something wrong with this?

I am not sure if I have some misconfiguration issue or is this a default behavior?

Comment: What's means by *doesn't work longer*? Do you know what *session timeout* is?

Comment: I have explained what I mean: client has to refresh the page to make it works again, so to make links work.

Comment: @skuntsel please provide the answer if you know

Comment: To be able to help I *need to understand* your problem first.

Comment: probably just found the answer, thank you very much, you helped me, I omitted these params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Glassfish admin console -> Configurations -> server-config -> Web
>   Container -> Session Timeout

set to 0: session never expires

http://www.cryptoengine.org/component/content/article/42-subinstall/68-configure-glassfish31.html

Answer (score 2):

where_is_tftp's answer worked on mine for a while, but my glassfish eventually stopped working, throwing a `NullPointerException at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:922).` To reset the timeout using asadmin since the gui was down, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7710116/1361683), which gives this command:

`asadmin set server.web-container.session-config.session-properties.timeout-in-seconds=3600`

Sidenote: I wanted to post this as a comment on the previous answer but don't have 50 rep. If someone does and sees this, feel free to repost it as a comment and delete this answer.